# Datadumps of SF, MSO and SU too?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-dump, superuser, serverfault

Considering the interesting graphs and such that have been generated from the SO datadump, has it been suggested yet, or planned, to release datadumps for the rest of the trilogy-sites? I'm curious what types of data could be pulled from querying all three, and having access to the history of users with connected-accounts.

**Update:**

> June 29, 2009 - [Jeff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/data-dump-for-serverfault/438#438),
>
> We will do this, but I agree with Michael -- there's not enough data yet. Plus, we'd like to "perfect" the process with the SO data dump before extending it to the other sites.
>
> Check back in a few months...

Comment: Partial dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/data-dump-for-serverfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff answered this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/data-dump-for-serverfault/438#438).